# Drag file on dialog with MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to drag file on dialog and get the file's path.
So I searched web and tried that.

MyDlg.cpp

```
KmCdmMakeMultiProjectDlg::KmCdmMakeMultiProjectDlg(CWnd* pParent)
: CDialog (KmCdmMakeMultiProjectDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
}

void KmCdmMakeMultiProjectDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST_MULTIPART, lst_AddList);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BTN_ADD_PROJECT, btn_AddList);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BTN_ADDLIST_CSV, btn_AddList_CSV);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BTN_DEL_PROJECT, btn_DelList);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BTN_TARGET_SELECT, btn_ReferFolder);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BTN_FILE_SELECT, btn_ReferCSV);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BTN_EXECUTE, btn_Execute);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BTN_EDIT_NAME, btn_EditName);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BTN_EDIT_DESCRIPTION, btn_EditDescription);
    DDX_Control(pDX, ID_CLOSE, btn_Close);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(KmCdmMakeMultiProjectDlg, CDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BTN_ADD_PROJECT, &KmCdmMakeMultiProjectDlg::AddList)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BTN_ADDLIST_CSV, &KmCdmMakeMultiProjectDlg::AddListCSV)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BTN_DEL_PROJECT, &KmCdmMakeMultiProjectDlg::DelList)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BTN_TARGET_SELECT, &KmCdmMakeMultiProjectDlg::SelectPath)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BTN_FILE_SELECT, &KmCdmMakeMultiProjectDlg::SelectCSV)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BTN_EXECUTE, &KmCdmMakeMultiProjectDlg::MakeExecute)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BTN_EDIT_NAME, &KmCdmMakeMultiProjectDlg::EditName)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BTN_EDIT_DESCRIPTION, &KmCdmMakeMultiProjectDlg::EditDescription)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(ID_CLOSE, &KmCdmMakeMultiProjectDlg::CloseDialog)
    ON_WM_DROPFILES()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL KmCdmMakeMultiProjectDlg::OnInitDialog() 
{   
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    CDialog::DragAcceptFiles();
}

void KmCdmMakeMultiProjectDlg::OnDropFiles(HDROP hDropInfo)
{
    CString csfile = "Why don't come this break point!";
    CDialog::OnDropFiles(hDropInfo);
}
```

I thought it is not difficult.
Just set message `ON_WM_DROPFILES()` in dialog,
And Set `CDialog::DragAcceptFiles();` in dialog's `OnInitDialog()` method.

I expected that `OnDropFiles(HDROP hDropInfo)` is run if I drag a file on dialog.
I have tested with debug mode, and checked break point in `OnDropFiles` method.
But didn't occur anything even though I dropped a file.

Have you any some idea?, waiting your teaching.
Thank you.

Comment: What are you dragging *from*?

Comment: Mark Ransom // csv file in C:\

Answer (score 0):

If application run as administrator, must include this 2 line before DragAcceptFiles();

For example.

```
BOOL KmCdmMakeMultiProjectDlg::OnInitDialog() 
{   
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    ChangeWindowMessageFilter(0x0049, MSGFLT_ADD);
    ChangeWindowMessageFilter(WM_DROPFILES, MSGFLT_ADD);
    CDialog::DragAcceptFiles();
}
```

Points are ChangeWindowMessageFilter.

Thank you.

Comment: There's a *reason* Microsoft won't let an administrator program accept input from a non-administrator source. Bypassing it is inviting trouble. The best recourse is to make your app not require administrator rights.

Answer (score 0):

In the name of the C++ an C, do not use ChangeWindowMessageFilter.
This deals with Privilege Isolation (UIPI) message filter and has nothing to do with drag and drop support.

You have to call **DragAcceptFiles**  for any windows object that is going to accept drag and drop by processing the WM_DROPFILES message. 
It has to be called when the object is attached to a window (valid m_hWnd)

Comment: If you look at`OnInitDialog` you'll find the call to `DragAcceptFiles`.

Comment: DragAcceptFiles IS NOT included in the code generated by Visual Studio. It is merely a commented out suggestion in the app class for SDI/MDI generated code.

Comment: If you mean the code shown by user5949771, I am sorry but I missed it for some reason.

Comment: I mean the code in the question! That code was highly edited, but it was in the original version as well.

Comment: I am not sure why I have missed it, thanks for pointing it to me.

Comment: user5949771
I have written a small sample with VS 2010, you can download from:https://www.dropbox.com/s/7wo8b4z91y02qeh/DragDropDlg.zip?dl=0
I would need your entire project to debug in order to help you.
Make sure you are dropping file onto the dialog not on any of the dialog's controls.

Comment: If you want to drop file on the control, you should call DragAcceptFiles for the control. Another sample showing just that:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3g8n6d9egb9dc8s/DragDropDlg2.zip?dl=0

Comment: Give up. The reason it didn't work is in their self-answer: the program is running as administrator, so you can't drop files from a non-administrator app without going through contortions. Of course that critical fact wasn't included in the original question.